# How can I track the event of opening a file in netrw in an autocommand?

Tags: vimrc, buffers, autocmd, netrw

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68285832/9995367) by creating an autocommand which will track when a new buffer is opened through `netrw`, and will then immediately close `netrw` once the buffer is closed.

How can I track the event of opening a new file in a new buffer through `netrw`? Specifically, I want to know when netrw opens a file (for the first time).

Comment: Yes, exactly! @D.BenKnoble

Comment: PS Welcome to [vi.se]!